# Can CURL submit a form without input field (HTML attribute) name?

Tags: php, curl

I have a unique situation that I haven't been able to find an answer to. I have a form that looks like the following:

```
<form>
  <input id="username" />
  <input id="password" />
  <button id="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

I'm trying to submit this form using `CURL`. I know how to do it if the html `name`, and form `action` attributes were set. But can this be done if they are not? In essence, this... `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'username='.$user.'&password='.$pass);` can't be done, I don't think.

Anyone aware of a better approach to resolve this?

Thank you!

Comment: I don't understand the question - you can POST to an endpoint using the action tag which would allow you to receive the data at an endpoint of your choosing.

For what reason do you not want to use action tags?

Comment: I agree with you, and thank you. However, this is not a form that I designed, and I can't change it. To better phrase the question: There is a form with no `action` in the form tag, and no `name` in the input tags. Is there a way to submit such a form via CURL?

Comment: Where does the form submit to? If you have access to the endpoint you could do a redirect - if you don't have access to where the form submits you'd have as much luck altering Stackoverflows forms

Comment: It isn't explicitly set in the html code. I'll see if I can look into the redirect approach. Thanks for the help.